# codeigniter-Model group by 2 model result

Tags: codeigniter

I have two different model function event_person1 and event_person5, i need to group by the result of two models with event_id, the models are here

```
public function event_person1($user_id){
$details1 ="select * from event where created_by={$user_id} order by created_date   desc";
$details = $this->db->query($details1);     
$res = $details->result_array();
return $res;
}

public function event_person5($employee_id,$user_id) {
$query="select distinct(event_id) from event_booth where booth_owner='{$employee_id}'";
$sql=$this->db->query($query);
$res=$sql->result_array();
$arr=array();
foreach($res as $r)
{ 
$data['id']=$r['event_id'];
$query1="select * from event where (event_id={$data['id']} and created_by!=      {$user_id})";
$sql1=$this->db->query($query1);
$res1=$sql1->result_array();
if(!empty($res1))
{
$arr[] = $res1;
}
unset($res1);
}
return $arr;
}
```

Comment: You have two functions not two models!! please can you explain what you want to do.

Comment: i want to sort the result of event_person1 and event_person5 in a array

Comment: can you give me example of the data in event_person1 and event_person5

Comment: i Get result for event_person1 as  Array ( [0] => Array ( [event_id] => 424 [event_name] => test [event_description] => test [start_date] => 2012-12-19 08:00:00.000 [end_date] => 2012-12-19 09:00:00.000 [userprofie_required] => [event_status_id] => 1 [open_to_all] => 1 [created_by] => 143416 [created_date] => 2012-12-18 09:54:00.000 [modified_by] => [modified_date] => [tag] => comma  )

Comment: i get result for event_person5 as Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [event_id] => 420 [event_name] => test [event_description] => asd  [start_date] => 2012-12-06 08:00:00.000 [end_date] => 2012-12-08 11:00:00.000 [userprofie_required] => [event_status_id] => 1 [open_to_all] => 1 [created_by] => 143418 [created_date] => 2012-12-17 11:08:00.000 [modified_by] => [modified_date] => [tag] => asd)))

Comment: i need to merge the results of both event_person1 and event_person5 into a array and sort it with event_id

Comment: @ganeshrj thanks for ur curiosity to help, finally found the solution

Comment: good to know. Share your solution as the answer